# javascript regex saying illegal

Tags: javascript, replace, syntax-error

I was using the following code to detect all the javadoc comments in the pre elements to replace them with a color of my choice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
        arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!/))*\\*/g, '<font color="#3F5FBF">' + $& + '</font>');
    }
</script>
```

but it gives me the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

EDIT: changed the code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
    arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    var reg = /\\\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!\/))*\\*/;
    var cds = arr[i].innerHTML.match(reg);
    for (var j=0; j<cds.length; j++){
        arr[i].innerHTML = arr[i].innerHTML.replace(cds[j], '<font color="#3F5FBF">' + cds[j] + '</font>'); 
    }
}
prettyPrint();
</script>
```

But the error changes to

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null start-ahead.html:234
```

(anonymous function)

Comment: The unexpected token is probably ``\`` after `/\\/*`. Look at the syntax highlighter, your escape is wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling is right, and there's another error in `(?!/)`. Replace it with `(?!\/)`

Comment: @FelixKling is right, OP is escaping the escape character and not escaping the scope character. Just as Mark explained in his answer. +1 for Mark.

Comment: Syntax errors are something you should be able to fix by yourself. SO is not your personal debugger. Your expression is still incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the 234 line of your code `start-ahead.html:234`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here `/\\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!/))*\\*/g`, when you used the `\\` and then used `/`. The program understands that your regex is like this `/\\/` and what comes after results in an error. Try this regex:

```
/\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!\/))*\\*/g
```

Or, depending on what you want:

```
/\\\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!\/))*\\*/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) needs a string as a second parameter. The [patterns in it to be replaced with captures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) need to be in that string.

You try to build that string out of two string literals and a variable named "`$&`". Yet, that is an illegal name - the "`&`" is a [bitwise AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and <s>lacks a second operand, because it is followed by "`+`" - SyntaxError.</s> will produce an horrible runtime error.

Also, as @FelixKling mentioned, your regexp is badly escaped. It might should be something like `new Regexp("\\/*\*\*([^\*]|\*(?!/))*\\*", "g")`, yet then there were some useless backslashes. What do you want to approach? Is it `/\*{3}([^*]|\*(?!\/))\**/g`?

Comment: @Mark: It won't produce this error, but it will nevertheless be a problem once the expression is fixed.

Comment: This operation does not create an error though. Assuming `$` is defined, `'a' + $& + 'b'` just results in `0`. I assume the whole expression is evaluated as `'a' + $ & (+'b')` (the second `+` being an unary plus).